# Angular html is breaking in VS Code

Tags: angular

[image]

So as you can see in the image. Angular is breaking in VS Code.
I'm not sure which one causing it.

This should be the code.

```html
<p-column field="" header="{{'CUCCommand' | translate}}" [style]="{'width':'15%'}">
  <template let-app="rowData" pTemplate="body">
    <img src="{{app.del}}" [ngClass]="app.delIsTrue? 'imgOn': 'imgOff'" (click)="appCRUD(app,app.delIsTrue,'APP_REMOVE')">
    <img src="{{app.ins}}" [ngClass]="app.insIsTrue? 'imgOn': 'imgOff'" (click)="appCRUD(app,app.insIsTrue,'APP_INSTALL')">
    <img src="{{app.upd}}" [ngClass]="app.updIsTrue? 'imgOn': 'imgOff'" (click)="appCRUD(app,app.updIsTrue,'APP_INSTALL')">
  </template>
</p-column>
```

Is it some kind of File Encoding Issue?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: have you tried using `[src]="app.something"` ?